# WCF REST: newb: Relationship between IService1.cs, Service1.svc, Service1.cs

Tags: c#, wcf

I apologize for such a basic question.

(.NET is great, but the complexity for something simple is... Classic .asp, php, etc are so much simpler to conceptualize.)

I followed the tutorials, and I have a simple REST service running on WCF, using VS 2010/.NET v4.

Works great, I can mod params, etc.

But I stare and stare at it, and do not fully understand the relationship between the units:

IService1.cs
Service1.svc
Service1.cs

Any and all elucidation very welcome.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Service1.svc is what you call in your browser to call the web service. This would be the like calling a web page.
This file points to the actual class that has code implementation for your web services. The other two files are Interface and Class that implements that interface. The reason for this is good practice.
It's actually not that complicated, just very good organized.

Comment: So if I want to rename the entry point/url, I rename Service1.svc and the references to it? (I understand that good organization is important, I just think that a nice, verbose explanation should come from the templates that create these projects, instead of assuming the dev knows or will figure out...)

Comment: If you want to rename the file, rename it, but you should also rename it in your web.config in case you have it referenced there. If you open the file, you will notice it points to a class by using the full namespace name, so if you rename the class and namespace, you should update it in the .svc file. The file and the class name don't have to match.